# Symfony Login return Invalid credentials

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8, I have implemented a login form, when I submit the form with correct credentials, its always returning "Invalid credentials" Error.

**app/config/security.yml**

```
security:

encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: email

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
```

**AppBundle/Controller/UserController**

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('user/login.html.twig', array(
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        'email' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

**login.html.twig**

```
{% if error %}
                    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
                {% endif %}
                <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post" class="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="_email" value="{{ email }}" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And also I have created User Entity as per this link [link](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/entity_provider.html#security-crete-user-entity)

I have implemented registration form that is working fine and users are stored in the database, but login is always returning Invalid Credentials. Table name is db is "users".

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that your form action path is incorrect. You should redirect to login check instead of login. In fos user bundle its fos_user_security_check

Comment: Please check this link http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/form_login_setup.html

---It has both login path and check path to same login path.

Comment: Have you checked the `var/logs` to see if they show more info? Everything above seems correct.

Comment: Could you please tell me where is var directory ? I can see app/logs directory which contains '.gitkeep', 'dev.log' and 'prod.log ' files. 'dev.log' file contains all the errors that i encountered during implementation.